# pasting file side by side

Tags: python-3.x, bash, numpy, for-loop, awk

I have many `ascii` files in a directory, i just want to sort the file name numerically and want to paste side by side.
Secondly, after pasting i want to make all the column of same length by appending zero at the end.

My files are named as

```
 data_Z_1   data_N_457 data_E_45
  1.5          1.2       2.3
  2.0          2.3       1.8
               4.5
```

At first I just want sort the above file names numerically as given below  and then want to paste side by side as

```
data_Z_1  data_E_45 data_N_457
  1.5       2.3      1.2
  2.0       1.8      2.3
                     4.5
```

Secondly i need to make all the columns equal length in a pasted file, so that output should be like

```
   1.5    2.3    1.2
   2.0    1.8    2.3
   0.0    0.0    4.5

I tried as below:
ls data_*_* | sort -V
```

But it doesnot work.Can anybody help me overcoming this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
paste $(ls data* | sort -t_ -k3n) | awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "") $i = "0.0"} 1'
```

Output:

```
1.5     2.3     1.2
2.0     1.8     2.3
0.0     0.0     4.5
```

- `sort -t_ -k3n` sets the field separator to `_` and numerically sorts
  the filenames on the 3rd field values.
- The options `-F'\t' -v OFS='\t'` to the awk command assign
  input/output field separator to a tab character.
- The awk statement `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "") $i = "0.0"`
  scans the input fields and sets `0.0` for the empty fields.
- The final `1` is equivalent to `print $0` to print the fields.

**[Edit]**
If you have huge number of files, it may exceed the capability of bash. Here is an alternative with `python` using `dataframe`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import pandas as pd
import re

files = glob.glob('data*')
files.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.sub(r'.*_', '', x)))    # sort filenames numerically by its number

dfs = []                                                # list of dataframes
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=[f])         # read file and assign column
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')       # force the cell values to floats
    dfs.append(df)                                      # add as a new column
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer')               # create a dataframe from the list of dataframes
df = df.fillna(0)                                       # fill empty cells
print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))          # print the dataframe removing index and header
```

which will produce the same results.

Comment: if i have few no of files it works but if i have nearly 5000 of data files it shows paste: data_N_1021: Too many open files

Comment: `5000 of data files` is a new and unpleasant information which **was not** noticed in the original post. I suppose it is commonly beyond the capability of bash and relevant commands. Do you prefer python solution instead? If so, please post your own python code first.

Comment: yes if possible please provide a python solution

Comment: I'd like you to show what you have tried with python **first**. Just a fragment of codes is good enough.

Comment: ok. import numpy as np; for file in glob.glob("data_*"): paste file

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good start point. It would be preferable if you can add the information of the problem what you cannot solve or what you cannot figure out.

Comment: ok...i am not that much experienced in python i am new to it.If you can help it would be better.

Comment: Understood. Please give me some time to write an answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `python` version. tested with 10,000 data files.

Comment: Thanks @tshiono for your answers,It helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. FYI I've updated my answer by simplifying the sort operation. Instead of sorting the dataframe, the filenames are sorted in advance. The code will be a bit simpler and faster. The output is identical to that of the previous version.